# Jmeter runs only first thread(first user)

Tags: multithreading, junit, jmeter

Jmeter is running only the 1st thread. On putting the load of 2 users, execution for only one user is getting completed successfully, for the other user, the execution gets completed as soon as it starts. The logs are below:-

2019-09-03 14:59:08,648 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group Advance Search 1-1

2019-09-03 14:59:13,653 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group Advance Search 1-2

2019-09-03 14:59:58,323 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group Advance Search 1-2

2019-09-03 14:59:58,323 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group Advance Search 1-2

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be getting something like:

[image]

Looking into your logs I can see the following:

1. 1st thread started at `2019-09-03 14:59:08,648`
2. 2nd thread started at `2019-09-03 14:59:13,653`
3. 2nd thread finished at `2019-09-03 14:59:58,323` (after 45 seconds)

So my expectation is that 1st thread is still running. If there are no any suspicious entries in jmeter.log file you can take a Thread Dump (the functionality is available since [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1/)) and see where exactly your 1st thread got stuck

[image]